# N/sftp Module - FTP_CANNOT_ESTABLISH_CONNECTION

Tags: server, connection, sftp, netsuite

I need to use a private rsa key to connect to a server, the file contains the key as follows.

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
key 
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

when I try to upload it, Setup/Compagny/Keys/add
I get the following error: Unexpected Error

If I try to convert it to .pem with the following bash command:

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f /path/to/key
```

(console log Key has comment 'amillet@LAPTOP-Q89B7RU7'
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase)

I am able to create the key so I am trying to establish a connection
with the code bellow :

```
sftp.createConnection({
    username: ID_OF_CONNECTION,
    keyId: KEY_ID
    hostKey: HOST_KEY,
    url: URL_SERVER,
    port: PORT_SERVER,
    });
```

I get the following error:**"FTP_CANNOT_ESTABLISH_CONNECTION", "details": "Could not establish connection to Auth fail. "**,

I then tried to connect via FileZilla with the same file (KEY_ID) and the same information, except the HOST_KEY is retrieved by filezilla

In my code HOST_KEY is the result of

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p ${PORT_SERVER} ${URL_SERVER}
```

executed from my terminal

I can't understand why the same information from fileZilla allows me to connect to the server but not from NEtsuite.

Comment: I am not intimately familiar with this topic, however have you tried the suggestions in Suite Answer 86330? (https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/86330/kw/86330)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the key Id from Setup -> Company Keys

your sample is missing the hostKeyType parameter

```
hostKeyType: 'rsa'
```

so:

```
sftp.createConnection({
    username: ID_OF_CONNECTION,
    keyId: KEY_ID
    hostKey: HOST_KEY,
    hostKeyType: 'rsa',
    url: URL_SERVER,
    port: PORT_SERVER,
});
```